# Typescript narrowing unable to parse out property type

Tags: typescript

I ran into this problem in my code:

```
interface Wide {
  prop: string | undefined
}

interface Narrow {
  prop: string
}

class Foo {
  prop: string
  constructor({ prop }: Narrow) {
    this.prop = prop
  }
}

const array = [{ prop: undefined }, { prop: 'foo' }]

array.forEach((obj: Wide) => {
  if (obj.prop && typeof obj.prop === 'string' && obj.prop !== undefined) {
    console.log(new Foo({ ...obj }))
    // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  }
})
```

Normally, I would think that Typescript would be able to deduce that if the `if` condition is passed, it means that the current `obj` that it is iterating on has a defined property `prop` with the type `string`. But I can't seem to get it to work.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrACYoN4ChnIAOUA9oQFzIDOYUoA5sgD7ICuIWMoEGuAvrlyhIsRCgBycKKQDuyPAWJlKNOiHr9BCADZwqVZADESJefiKkK1Wg3MISIVawRgSUABTYLZZH0qTpEhkASjMCAjAAC2AqADolQmQAXm9CcwEBXHtHMGQpKDgAT2TkAG0vBMp2Tm4MXwAaeVTKAHIYExbfAF1BfKLY9qgAUURI93cSACMAK0p0LFCkgD4w5GAYZAmZ%20MtkADI95DBCwggSDanpnZ8k2%20QW1QZOg%20RL68SAQjvqiC4QHlCCnC2SoJG0EFi2hI9Hc-zkxhInmQsRRl18wWC5gIAHpscgAConFAtH5-HidGLIEAkXJ6KjAeggOCTcFHUzHU73R7qFqxdL8YJAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Type guard (type predicate)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

```
interface Wide {
  prop: string | undefined
}

interface Narrow {
  prop: string
}

class Foo {
  prop: string
  constructor({ prop }: Narrow) {
    this.prop = prop
  }
}

const array = [{ prop: undefined }, { prop: 'foo' }]

function isNarrow(obj: Wide | Narrow): obj is Narrow {
  return typeof obj.prop === 'string';
}

array.forEach((obj: Wide) => {
  if (isNarrow(obj)) {
    console.log(new Foo({ ...obj }));
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrACYoN4ChnIAOUA9oQFzIDOYUoA5sgD7ICuIWMoEGuAvrlyhIsRCgBycKKQDuyPAWJlKNOiHr9BCADZwqVZADESJefiKkK1Wg3MISIVawRgSUABTYLZZH0qTpEhkASjMCAjAAC2AqADolQmQAXm9CcwEBXHtHMGQpKDgAT2TkAG0vBMp2Tm4MXwAaeVTKAHIYExbfAF1BGHYXYAdkGIDZdxIAIwArSnQsZmRRoODKSanhgyW5BWQoCDBWKBBkMELCCBIYZDX4y2SklJbVBhaAbk1cfKLY9qgAUUQkXc42ms0wEFCSQAfGFhld3CN8kEQVNgqEdgRslQSNoILFtCR6O4QBA5MYSJ5kLFqWtfGj3gQMsEgA)

Answer (score 1):

You could fix it by providing a custom [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```js
function isNarrow<T extends { prop: unknown }>(obj: T): obj is T & Narrow {
  return typeof obj.prop === 'string'
}

array.forEach((obj: Wide) => {
  if (obj.prop && isNarrow(obj)) {
    console.log(new Foo({ ...obj }))
  }
})
```

Note a few things:

1. I do not think there is any need to copy the object using the spread syntax. You can just pass the original object to the constructor.
2. I have kept the `obj.prop` part of the condition, but note that it does not accept the empty string. The `obj.prop !== undefined` part was not necessary because `obj.prop` cannot be undefined if its type is `'string'`.

---

An alternative solution is to just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```js
array.forEach((obj: Wide) => {
  if (obj.prop && typeof obj.prop === 'string') {
    console.log(new Foo({ ...obj } as Narrow))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `obj` is in `Wide` type even with `string` value (not `undefined`). So in this case you know more than ts compiler so you can use type assertion like this:

```
  if (obj.prop && typeof obj.prop === 'string' && obj.prop !== undefined) {
        let narrow:Narrow = obj as Narrow;
        console.log(new Foo(narrow))
    }
  }
```

[PlayGroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrACYoN4ChnIAOUA9oQFzIDOYUoA5sgD7ICuIWMoEGuAvrlyhIsRCgBycKKQDuyPAWJlKNOiHr9BCADZwqVZADESJefiKkK1Wg3MISIVawRgSUABTYLZZH0qTpEhkASjMCAjAAC2AqADolQmQAXm9CcwEBXHtHMGQpKDgAT2TkAG0vBMp2Tm4MXwAaeVTKAHIYExbfAF1BfKLY9qgAUURI93cSACMAK0p0LFCkgD4w5GAYZAmZ%20MtkADI95DBCwggSDanpnZ8k2%20QW1QZOg%20RL68SAQjvqiC4QHlCCnCwO0EFyIHyQXIAVkJUueQMMKCAG5zMCCNkqCRQbFtCR6O5-nJjCRCZCQsE0b50rhgkA)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the compiler can correctly narrow the type of `obj.prop`:

```js
if (obj.prop && typeof obj.prop === 'string' && obj.prop !== undefined) {
  console.log(new Foo({ prop: obj.prop }))
}
```

But isn't smart enough to narrow down the type of the whole `obj` in this case. You can get it to work if you rewrite `Wide` to be a union:

```js
type Wide = Narrow | {prop: undefined}
```

then the second variant will get filtered by the if statement.